# Matrix power in python

Tags: python, numpy

How to get matrix power of numpy.array in python? (It says not recommended to use nympy.matrix for linear algebra.). Could not find alternatives. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.linalg.matrix_power` for that.

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
import numpy as np

i = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]]) 
matrix_power(i, 3)
```

output:

```
array([[ 0, -1],
       [ 1,  0]])
```

You can read more about `numpy.linalg.matrix_power` from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I thought it was also meant not to use matrix_power.